# Почему не работает debug.log?

Tags: php, wordpress, php-fpm

Задаю в wp-config.php отладочные параметры согласно [инструкции в Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress):

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

При этом лог-файл не создаётся, вывод в созданный вручную файл `/wp-content/debug.log` не производится ни при каких настройках разрешений на файл.

На сервере включён php-fpm, может быть, в нём дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Причина**

Да, проблема связана с php-fpm. Что делает WordPress при указании

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

в `wp-config.php`? Код в `wp-includes/load.php` довольно простой

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    if ( WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY )
        ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    elseif ( null !== WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY )
        ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

    if ( WP_DEBUG_LOG ) {
        ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );
        ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
    }
} else {
    error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
}
```

Нам важна только одна строка

```
        ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
```

В ней WordPress пытается установить новый путь к файлу лога, а именно `wp-content/debug.log`. Вот только при включённом php-fpm эта функция возвращает false и не срабатывает. Почему?

Потому что на сервере в файле `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` (в самом конце) по умолчанию установлено:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Вот эти параметры не могут быть перекрыты вызовом `ini_set()`, в результате чего сделать вывод лога ошибок в `wp-content/debug.log` не получается.

**TL;DR (Решение)**

Надо закомментировать следующие строки на сервере в файле `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
;php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

и перезапустить php-fpm

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

После чего файл лога будет успешно создаваться и лог ошибок будет записываться в `wp-content/debug.log`.